# Possible to emulate a USB Mass Storage Device and connect to another machine in Linux?

Tags: linux, usb-storage, emulation

Is it possible to emulate a USB Mass Storage Device (HDD) with Linux?

For example, I want to be able to connect my Linux server to another machine and emulate a USB Mass Storage Device.

I'd like to be able to transfer files to/from it but I don't need the server and other machine to access the files at the same time. If I can disconnect, copy files, and reconnect that would be fine.

Comment: Yes. However, is your device equipped with a USB “device” or “OTG” controller? Because a USB “host” isn’t going to work. // Perhaps you should explain your original intent instead: Why do you need such a complicated setup just to transfer files?

Comment: Yea, please tell us what problem you're actually trying to solve. It's likely you'll find a more reasonable solution to THAT.